# Can we construct a universal Turing machine using only Peano's axioms for addition?

Tags: arithmetic, turing-machines, incompleteness

Can we construct a universal Turing machine (UTM) using only Peano's axioms for addition?

We know that arithmetic without addition is complete, and that adding multiplication makes it incomplete.

I am trying to understand more deeply if there is a link between incompleteness and the existence of a UTM.

It has been shown by Chaitin that a UTM can exists as a Diophantine equation involving multiplication, addition and exponential. So a UTM from full arithmetic is definitely possible. No claims however are made as to if this is the logically simplest or not.

Furthermore, a UTM moves tapes left and right, write a symbol, erase a symbol, or read a symbol. These does not seem to be multiplicative operations.

Comment: The piano's axioms?  I prefer drums.  Properly the name is Peano.

Comment: @Oscar Autocorrect...

Comment: Hate that thing.  I have had to make embarrassing edits to many answers when I spotted autocorrects.

Comment: But autocorrect can be misled by such cues as extra "the"s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can encode any TM and its non-blank tape content (assuming we started with a finite part of the tape non-blank at the stat) using recursive functions, and every recursive function is representable using the language of arithmetic. Thus, using the Peano Axioms you can prove for any $n$ what the state (internal state and tape configuration (which includes osirion of head along tape)) is that the TM is in after $n$ steps of operation. So that is indeed how you could construct a kind of UTM: a UTM that *proves* using the Peano Axioms, together with a logic statement describing the initial state and input of a TM, what things look like every step of the way.

Answer (score 5):

Presumably what you describe as Peano's axioms for addition has been studied as [Presburger arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presburger_arithmetic), which is known to be consistent and complete (therefore decidable).  This seems to disallow the "embedding" of a universal Turing machine in that theory since then the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) would be decidable.